# How to send a password to iBook buyers?

Tags: app-store-connect, ibooks-author, books

I'm publishing a textbook on iTunes Connect that has facilitator sections as HTML widgets. I'd like to password protect them as sometimes they have answers to quizzes that ideally the student doesn't see. I've created the widget and have it password protected, but I'm not sure how to communicate a password to the iBook buyer.

Is there a way to get an email from iTunes Connect or something unique to the iBook?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get an email address from the buyers of your book. iTunes Connect doesn't provide that kind of information.

What you could do is write a note next to the widget with an email address where the buyers can mail to. To get the password from you.

Or the note contains a link to a website where you can provide the password.